# Cannot import umap: cannot import name 'structref' from 'numba.experimental'

Tags: python, anaconda, runumap

I tried to import umap in my jupyter notebook but had the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'structref' from 'numba.experimental' (C:\Users\name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\experimental\__init__.py)
```

I tried to update conda but doesn't work. What can I do ?

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried to update conda"?

Comment: conda update --all
or conda install -c conda-forge umap-learn

Comment: Can you share the list of packages in the environment?

Comment: Hello @AMC, I uninstalled anaconda et installed it again and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

The `numba.experimental` subpackage was added in version 0.51.0.  You can check your version of number using:

```
import numba

numba.__version__
```

If it is less then 0.51.0, you will need to install a newer version.

```
conda install numba=0.51.*
```